# Regular expressions to add classes to html tags

Tags: javascript

I am working on a reactjs project and have basic html coming through via json. I need to go back over the markup and append bootstrap classes to it so its styled properly on the page.

the current function

```
  const markupFormatting = (html) => {
    html = html.replace(/<p/g, '<p class="paragraph-margin-bottom-10 text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified"')
    html = html.replace(/<a/g, '<a class="text--font-size-14 hyperlink-primary"')
    return html
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/64/

Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: why are you not returning the html already with the classes?

Comment: `<address>`, `<aside>`, `<article>`, `<pre>` - these will be matched by your regex. [Do not use regex for HTML parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: @ValterJunior -- well the data will be coming from a json call - I'd rather keep all style controlling at the template level -- then ask a backend dev to code these styles into the api

Comment: I'm not sure how this question relates to React...In general, it doesn't really sound like your current backend is a good fit for React, if it's returning chunks of HTML.

Comment: @mingos - that is possible too - well - is there a stricter regex to use - or way of just adding the classes in a more pure react js way?

Comment: @TomFenech - its a reactjs project -- the data is coming from json -- language switching etc.. so I am trying to pick up html - but apply styles at template level

Comment: @TheOldCounty why not just match the tags using `document.querySelectorAll()` or `document.getElementsByTagName()` and then `classList.add()` on the results?

Comment: html.getElementsByTagName("p").classList.add("paragraph-margin-bottom-10 text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified")   --- html.getElementsByTagName is not a function 
 http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/65/

Comment: Because `html` is a string and these methods are for DOM elements. You would have to use `document.createElement("div")` and then set the `innerHTML` to your string. By the way, I am removing the React tag from your question. If there's something React-specific that you want to ask about, then feel free to edit your question and add the tag back in.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to parse the HTML and add the classes

```
const $html = $(html);
$html.find('p').addClass('paragraph-margin-bottom-10 text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified');
$html.find('a').addClass('text--font-size-14 hyperlink-primary');
return $html.html();
```

This protects you from a few edge cases, e.g. adding a duplicate `class` property. This works on the server side as well with [the cheerio library](https://cheerio.js.org/).

PS: There is this jewel about using RegEx to work with HTML: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Its a reactjs project - was a bit dubious of appending the jquery lib to the approach. I've not had to include it yet --

Comment: Maybe I should add it to the component - its already in the package

Comment: There is nothing wrong using jQuery to accomplish this. The only thing one needs to look out for is not to use both libraries for **DOM manipulation**. What this code does is string --> html parsing in a function and returns a list of elements which then React can use to render. Excellent solution... +1

Comment: @kraf - getting a jquery import problem? import {$} from 'jquery'

Comment: Try without the curlies: `import $ from 'jquery'` or if you are using Typescript `import * as $ from 'jquery'`. If it doesn't work, post the error message, we'll figure it out.

Comment: _ fixed it -- but the code you have isn't working -- it spews out just the first paragraph

Comment: I updated it: http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/70/. I forgot about `.html()` only returning the content of the first matched node, sorry! I wrapped the source in a div before parsing with jQuery.

Comment: is there a better way than wrapping a div around it?

Comment: this isn't working -- const $html = $(html).wrap( "<div/");

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in this way:

```
  var html1 = '<p>some test with a <a href="text">link</a></p><p>another paragraph with a <a href="test2">link</a></p>';

  function markupFormatting(html1){
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = html1;

    e.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(obj,i){obj.setAttribute("class", "abc")});

    return e;
  }

  console.log(markupFormatting(html1))
```